# How to button_click function for dynamically created button column in datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

How to create button click function for dynamically created button column.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn select = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
select.Text = "Details";
select.HeaderText = "Details";
select.Name = "Select";
dataGridView5.Columns.Add(select);
```

This is the code I have used to create button dynamically in my datagridview.

Can you give an example on how to write `button_click` function for onclick of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the CellContentClick-Event

Example:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);

        DataGridViewButtonColumn select = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        select.Text = "Details";
        select.HeaderText = "Details";
        select.Name = "Select";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(select);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Select"].Index)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Clicked! Row: {0}", e.RowIndex));
        }
    }
```

[CellContentClick on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may handle either  `DataGridView.CellClick` or `DataGridView.CellContentClick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can associate with `CellClick` event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/libr...0s(VS.80).aspx

Or with this exemple very interessant

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f4ff8/datagridviewlinkcolumn-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-in-C-Sharp/